# Using constant struct members in array declaration

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, enums

I am writing a small toy project (a datastructure) where I have a collection of constants that I would like to bundle in an anonymous struct that lives in the main class. This class uses some of the constants to declare the size of static arrays.
It looks somewhat like this:

```
template< class T, size_t K >
class Tree {
    static struct {
        size_t const min_keys{ K };
        size_t const max_keys{ 2*K };
        ...
    } const constants;
    ...
};
```

`K` is a template parameter, and all the members of the struct are const. However, the compiler (I am using g++ 5.1) complains when declaring an static array.

```
bpt.h:34:34: error: size of array is not an integral constant-expression
     T keys[constants.max_keys];
```

This confuses me – everything is `const`. I am merely trying to clean up my constants, bundling them like this seemed ideal and interesting. Using an enum class would be nice too, but as the class also needs to compare against those constants, is out of the question. Right now I am using an anonymous enum which does work, but this has stirred my curiosity.

Why is this? Is this a bad idea? I am very new to C++ – I would be thrilled to see alternatives.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://ideone.com/a8jsuh) -- get a better compiler?

Comment: Same here, what you've got compiles for me on MSVS2013. What are you using? Also, is there code where you create an instance that you're not showing here?

Comment: Note however that you will probably have to provide a definition for the static constant member at some point, and to do so, you may find it awkward to say its type if you don't give the type a name. Alternatively, make the static member [constexpr](https://ideone.com/LK4nX1), in which case you can use the member values as constant expressions, too.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: You are even trying to reproduce it. The point is in extra code `T keys[constants.max_keys];` declaration. That's what you a have to compile.

Comment: @AnT: Use [constexpr](https://ideone.com/LK4nX1). And the OP's code doesn't contain the problematic example!

Comment: I agree with @KerrekSB:  `constants`, being an object of class type, cannot be used inside a constant expression unless you define it as `constexpr` (instead/additionally to `const`). IIRC, the committee chose to not extend/relax the usability of `const` objects in constant expressions to encourage using `constexpr` instead.

Comment: For C++03 one can make the constants `static` and name the struct type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, std::size_t K>
struct Tree {
    static constexpr struct {
    //     ^^^^^^^^^
        std::size_t const min_keys{ K };
        std::size_t const max_keys{ 2*K };
    } constants {};
    //         ^^^
};
```

Example usage:

```
int main()
{
    int foo[Tree<int, 20>::constants.min_keys] = {1, 2};
}
```

The key point is to make `Tree::constants` a `constexpr` static data member, which means that its members are *constant expressions* that can be used as, say, array sizes. Note:

- static constexpr members need initializers, hence the `{}` (or we could have put `{K, 2 * K}` here and left off the brace-or-equal initializers).
- You don't need a definition for the static constexpr member as long as you don't odr-use it (e.g. don't try to compute `&Tree<int, 3>::constants`). This is convenient.

Comment: @eudaemonia: No problem. I'd still consider it a bit bad for readability to not give the inner class a name, but it certainly works. If it solves your problem, go for it.